# How do I use CredentialProvider-nextauth with Grafbase

Tags: authentication, next.js, graphql, next-auth, credential-providers

I am using Next-auth and Grafbase in this project.

I've added GoogleProviders into my project but now want to add login through credentials option in my website for practice and to get the idea of how it works.

This is my session.ts file

```
// ! In session we are going to store all the data about the currently logged in 

import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { NextAuthOptions, User } from 'next-auth';
import { AdapterUser } from 'next-auth/adapters';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { SessionInterface, UserProfile } from '@/types/index';
import { createUser, getUser } from './actions';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";


export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: 'Email',
                    type: 'email',
                },
                password: {
                    label: 'Password',
                    type: 'password',
                }
            },

            // Error: The expected type comes from property 'authorize' which is declared here on type 'UserCredentialsConfig<{ email: { label: string; type: string; }; password: { label: string; type: string; }; }>'
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    // get the user if they exist
                    const { user } = await getUser(credentials?.email as string) as { user?: UserProfile };
                    const userExists = await getUser(user?.email as string) as { user?: UserProfile };
    
                    // if they don't exist, create a new one
                    if (!userExists.user) {
                        await createUser(
                            // Error (user is already is possibly undefined)
                            user.name as string,
                            user.email as string,
                            user.image as string
                        );
                    }
                    // return the user/ true
                    return true;
    
                } catch (error: any) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    jwt: {
        encode: ({ secret, token }) => {
            const encodedToken = jsonwebtoken.sign({
                ...token,
                iss: 'grafbase',
                exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60
            }, secret);
            return encodedToken;
        },
        decode: async ({ secret, token }) => {
            const decodedToken = jsonwebtoken.verify(token!, secret);
            return decodedToken as JWT;
        },
    },
    theme: {
        colorScheme: 'light',
        logo: '/hero.png',
    },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session }) {
            const email = session?.user?.email as string;

            try {
                const data = await getUser(email) as { user?: UserProfile }
                const newSession = {
                    ...session,
                    user: {
                        ...session.user,
                        ...data?.user,
                    }
                }
                return newSession;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`Error retrieving user data`, error);
                return session;
            }
        },
        async signIn({ user }: { user: AdapterUser | User }) {
            try {
                // get the user if they exist
                const userExists = await getUser(user?.email as string) as { user?: UserProfile };

                // if they don't exist, create a new one
                if (!userExists.user) {
                    await createUser(
                        user.name as string,
                        user.email as string,
                        user.image as string
                    );
                }
                // return the user/ true
                return true;

            } catch (error: any) {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            }


        },
    }

}

export async function getCurrentUser() {

    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions) as SessionInterface;

    return session;
}
```

actions.ts:

```
import { createUserMutation, getUserQuery } from "@/garphql";
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const apiUrl = isProduction ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAFBASE_API_URL || '' : 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql';

const apiKey = isProduction ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAFBASE_API_KEY || '' : '1234';

const serverUrl = isProduction ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL : 'http://localhost:3000';

const client = new GraphQLClient(apiUrl as string, {
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': process.env.apiKey as string,
    }
});

const makeGraphQLRequest = async (query: string, variables = {}) => {
    try {
        // client request
        return await client.request(query, variables);

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }

}

export const getUser = (email: string) => {
    client.setHeader('x-api-key', apiKey);
    return makeGraphQLRequest(getUserQuery, { email })

}

export const createUser = (name: string, email: string, avatarUrl: string) => {
    client.setHeader('x-api-key', apiKey);
    const variables = {
        input: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            avatarUrl: avatarUrl
        }
    }

    return makeGraphQLRequest(createUserMutation, variables)
}
```

I referred to the documentations of grafbase and nextauth repeatedly but no use. I am a beginner. I added googleauth with the help of tutorial but I can't find one for credentialsauth.